# Pivot Longer charter headings

Tags: r, pivot-table, tidyr

I Have data set with the following column names

```
[1] "OdName" "AreaName" "RegName" "DevName" "1980" "1981"
[7] "1982" "1983" "1984" "1985" "1986" "1987"
[13] "1988" "1989" "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993"
[19] "1994" "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999"
[25] "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005"
[31] "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011"
[37] "2012" "2013"
```

Have a pivot longer problem from the point of view that I need to pivot all the year columns into one column "Years". If the column heading with numeric it would be easy.

```
pivot_longer(
cols =c(1980:2013),
names_to = "Years",
values_to = "Count")
```

So a little bit lost on how to pivot a series of charter column heading.
I need the character equivalent of 1980:2013

Comment: Look up `as.character`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"character equivalent of 1980:2013"* taken literally is `as.character(1980:2013)`. The reason it fails without it is that `pivot_longer` will try to index on the column numbers (meaning the 1980th column).

```r
dat <- data.frame(OdName='a', AreaName='b', RegName='c', DevName='d', "1980"=1, "1981"=2, "1982"=3, check.names = FALSE)
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, 1980:1982, names_to = "Years", values_to = "Count")
# Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
# x Locations 1980, 1981, and 1982 don't exist.
# i There are only 7 columns.
```

The key is *Locations* (and slightly less-so "only 7 columns"). If it were looking for *names* `1980` etc, then it would have erred with:

```
# x Column `1980` doesn't exist.
```

(but it does, of course)

Instead, use `as.character`:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, as.character(1980:1982), names_to = "Years", values_to = "Count")
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#   OdName AreaName RegName DevName Years Count
#   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a      b        c       d       1980      1
# 2 a      b        c       d       1981      2
# 3 a      b        c       d       1982      3
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Prefect

Comment: You could also backquote `pivot_longer(dat, `1980`:`1982`, names_to = 'Years', values_to = 'Count')`